# MKPolyline and memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
NSUInteger numPoints = [[self locationFake] count];
CLLocationCoordinate2D *pointsPtr = malloc(numPoints * sizeof(CLLocationCoordinate2D));

for(int counter=0; counter<numPoints; counter++) {
    pointsPtr[counter] = [[[self locationFake] objectAtIndex:counter] coordinate];
}

// (1)
MKPolyline *polyline = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:pointsPtr count:numPoints];
```

...

```
free(pointsPtr);
pointsPtr = NULL;
```

After I have created the `MKPolyline` object (1) can I free the memory used by the points, or does the `MKPolyline` keep referencing that memory after its creation and I should not free the points until I am done with the `MKPolyline` object in its entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you can free the memory.  I use a stack-allocated fixed-size buffer and it works fine, which means the polyline must be copying those coordinates somewhere.

Comment: Hi there, I already used MKMapPoint* pointArr = malloc(sizeof..) , free(pointArr). While I still face with memory issue. Any other guidance?